# Java ServerSocket app's actions

Tags: java, сокет, многопоточность

У меня есть Клиент-Серверное приложение, где сервер, естественно, обрабатывает запросы в разных новосоздаваемых потоках, а клиент просто отсылает и принимает данные в одном потоке при помощи Socket. Но например я отсылаю файл, который задерживает поток и "замораживает" все GUI на несколько секунд, если не больше.

Но все команды у меня состоят из запросов, возможно что-то произойдет с сервером или медленное интернет соединение и GUI будет глючить?

Правильно ли будет каждое нажатие кнопки клиента обрабатывать в отдельном потоке, чтобы предотвратить задержку GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал в отдельном потоке сделать очередь, в которую вы добавляете задания. При нажатии на кнопку отправлять в очередь команд. А там в читать команды и отправлять по сокету. В простейшем варианте что-то типо такого:

```
public class Worker extends Thread {
        private static final int SLEEPING_TIME = 50;
        private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Command> mCommands = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Command>();

        public void addCommand(Command cmd){
            mCommands.add(req);
        }

        public void run() {
            while(true){
                if(mCommands.size() > 0 ){
                    Command req = mCommands.poll();
                    // здесь пишем в сокет что-то
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(SLEEPING_TIME);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

В основном потоке запустите этот поток:

```
Worker worker = new Worker();
worker.start();
```

По нажатию на кнопку вызывайте:

```
 worker.addCommand(new Command(...));
```

`Command` ваш класс какой-то, который в себе содержит данные для запроса.

Comment: Да, хорошее решение, но по сути это решение просто более элегантнее, но по работе не сильно медленнее чем просто сразу создавать поток и стартовать при каждом нажатии кнопки?
 ну к примеру
       
@FXML
void someHandler(){
new Thread( new Runnable() {
    "@"Override
    public void run() {
       // some code here....
    }
).start();
}

просто при вашем решении мне прийдется очень много чего переделывать, но если оно действительно сильно отличается, то прийдется

Comment: @ОлегМорозов если запросов по сокету мало будет, то можно и разовый `Runnable` создавать на каждую задачу.

Comment: ну у меня автоматический запрос раз в секунду, плюс пользователь иногда ( в среднем раз в 30 секунд) при взаимодействии с UI отсылает запросы
Ну вообщем я понял насчет этого, у меня главный вопрос не в том как создавать потоки, а вообще это норма, что если в интерфейсе ключевых кнопок, слайдеров итд штук 15, которые отправляют запросы на сервер, то это норма, что каждый из них обрабатывается в отдельном потоке?